# XAMPP mysql access without password

Tags: mysql, xampp, passwords

When I access mysql database on my localhost XAMPP installation I usually type

> mysql -u user -p

But today I accidentally mistyped it like this:

> mysql -u user-p

And for my surpries got connected without any password prompt. I tried that with many users registered in mysql and it seems they all get opened like this. Is that a bug or vulnerability for XAMPP or is it the normal behaviour for the integrated shell application inside the control panel? And if it is the second, how can I change it because anyone else using my computer can easily access any database and table on my server?

Comment: Its not a bug, in command, (-) is required to distinguish command syntax.

Comment: So how can I restrict the access without using password for password protected users?

Comment: Well, this syntax might be the correct, but the second command I of ones written above gives me direct access to mysql with all previleges of the selected user no matter is it correct as syntax or is it not. I don't want to leave open any possibility to access particular user without having to type nothing else than its name and "-p" without space after that.   PS: I may have accidentally deleted your comment above, sorry about it, it wasn't intended.

Comment: if your main root password is null then everyone can access, so you must update root password and the try again.

Comment: But the problem is that it isn't null and if I type the command correctly, it prompts for password and doesn't allow logging in if is uncorrect. The direct access only occurs when the second command is entered.

Comment: did you try to use `use database`, surely there password will be required.

Comment: Nothing is required, I have full acces to all databases tables to which the user has previleges granted.

Comment: can you please give me your computer's team viewers id? so that i must check.

Comment: Haven't installed team viewer in here yet, let me install it first.

Comment: I have no reputation for chatting here yet, is there another way to give the team viewer details in here, without making them publically visible?

Comment: When you type `mysql` alone, I bet you'll be able to access the database still. I think the default installation has User=Any, Host=% Password=-- (you can check this in the Users tab of your PhpMyAdmin since you already have this with XAMPP)

Comment: Yes, I am able to access mysql with typing mysql only with only two databases listed - information_schema and test. There are 3 "Any" users in phpMyAdmin on hosts: % , localhost and linux the first has -- as password and the others has not any. But they seem not to have any priveleges granted. Don't those two databases require no previleges at all? And shouldI delete the Any users to prevent this way of logging in?

Comment: add me in skype, name: raja.jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> quote : RajaRassani
>
> When you type mysql alone, I bet you'll be able to access the database still. I think the default installation has User=Any, Host=% Password=-- (you can check this in the Users tab of your PhpMyAdmin since you already have this with XAMPP)

Actually it really appears to be user related issue, XAMPP adds too much useless users it seems... Thank you for helping!